# Who are the characters on the girls' planes in Shirobako?

Tags: shirobako

In the intro to Shirobako, the girls are shown flying in fighter jets. Each of them has a design under the cockpit - presumably related to the characters.

I can't figure them all out though.

[image]

This is the easiest one, the two toys are delusions of Aoi's that she interacts with often during the show.

[image]

Shizuka's plane has the  pig with a plum-shaped nose. This was the character that she got to play in costume during one of the episodes.

[image]

Misa's plane has a depiction of a penguin - from the show that inspired her to join the company she was making tires for.

However, I don't know what the final two are referring to.

[image]
[image]

Did I miss something obvious? Any ideas how these pictures / characters are related to the cast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ema's is one of the characters from their *Seven Lucky Battle Gods* anime.
[image: character]

I'm not sure about the one for Midori, but it might be the guy behind her in the red armour.

Comment: Hmm I don't believe Midori's is the guy behind the woman. The facial hair matches neither in color nor shape.

Answer (score 8):

[This blog post](http://metanorn.net/2015/03/shirobako-20) suggests that the final character might be **[Fyodor Dostoevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Dostoyevsky)**, a famous Russian author, journalist and philosopher.

[image]

We see that Midori is a big fan of Dostoevsky's in the anime occasionally, including dropping the title of arguably his most famous book [*Crime & Punishment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_and_Punishment).

[image]

Dostoevsky's influence is one of the reasons why Midori wanted to be a writer in the first place.